# Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I've seen a lot of other folks posting this question...

Trying to share a link from my WordPress site and comes with a "Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link." Checked OpenGraph settings on [Facebook OpenGraph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), installed Yoast SEO to edit OG tags, [removed OEmbed code](https://pmig.at/2017/10/26/linkedin-link-preview-for-wordpress/), still no dice.

Please let me know what else I can try.